# How to put index as recognizing same number of sorted array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**I'm dealing with immutable objects.**

I sort data by `thisweekNumber` as you can see below.

```
 data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.thisweekNumber - a.thisweekNumber;
          })
```

For exmaple,

```
data = [
{name: A, thisweekNumber: 3}, 
{name: B, thisweekNumber: 5}, 
{name: C, thisweeknumber: 1}, 
{name: D, thisweekNumber: 4}
{name: E, thisweekNumber: 4}
]
```

I sort them **B -> D -> E -> A -> C**

So I want to put Index to them in this order:

```
data = [
{name: A, thisweekNumber: 3, index: 3}, 
{name: B, thisweekNumber: 5, index: 1}, 
{name: C, thisweeknumber: 1, index: 4}, 
{name: D, thisweekNumber: 4, index: 2}
{name: E, thisweekNumber: 4, index: 2}
]
```

BUT here, I want to **recognize same thisweekNumber of D and E**.

Since they both have 4.

So Index will be like above.

How can I make this array in `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of is to do it after sorting, with a simple loop:

```
let index = 1;
for (let n = 0; n < data.length; ++n) {
    const current = data[n];
    current.index = index;
    // See if the next one (if any) matches this one
    if (data[n + 1]?.thisweekNumber !== current.thisweekNumber) {
        ++index;
    }
}
```

```js
const data = [
    { name: "A", thisweekNumber: 3 },
    { name: "B", thisweekNumber: 5 },
    { name: "C", thisweeknumber: 1 },
    { name: "D", thisweekNumber: 4 },
    { name: "E", thisweekNumber: 4 },
];
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.thisweekNumber - a.thisweekNumber;
    // return b.thisweekFeedNumber - a.thisweekFeedNumber;
});

let index = 1;
for (let n = 0; n < data.length; ++n) {
    const current = data[n];
    current.index = index;
    // See if the next one (if any) matches this one
    if (data[n + 1]?.thisweekNumber !== current.thisweekNumber) {
        ++index;
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note the use of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#array_item_access_with_optional_chaining) in the `if`.

---

In a comment you've said:

> thanks i understand the concept ! but my object seems not extensible in the process 'current.index = index'. erorr says : cannot add property index, object is not extensible.

You didn't mention that in the question. If you're dealing with immutable objects, you'll need to create new objects (probably in a new array). Creating the objects is typically done using spread syntax:

```
const newObject = {
    ...oldObject,
    newProperty: "new value"
};
```

You can easily do that in the loop above, pushing to an in-scope array:

```js
const data = [
    { name: "A", thisweekNumber: 3 },
    { name: "B", thisweekNumber: 5 },
    { name: "C", thisweeknumber: 1 },
    { name: "D", thisweekNumber: 4 },
    { name: "E", thisweekNumber: 4 },
];
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.thisweekNumber - a.thisweekNumber;
    // return b.thisweekFeedNumber - a.thisweekFeedNumber;
});

let index = 1;
const result = [];
for (let n = 0; n < data.length; ++n) {
    const current = data[n];
    result.push({
        ...current,
        index,
    });
    // See if the next one (if any) matches this one
    if (data[n + 1]?.thisweekNumber !== current.thisweekNumber) {
        ++index;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...or via `map`:

```js
const data = [
    { name: "A", thisweekNumber: 3 },
    { name: "B", thisweekNumber: 5 },
    { name: "C", thisweeknumber: 1 },
    { name: "D", thisweekNumber: 4 },
    { name: "E", thisweekNumber: 4 },
];
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.thisweekNumber - a.thisweekNumber;
    // return b.thisweekFeedNumber - a.thisweekFeedNumber;
});

let index = 1;
const result = data.map((current, n) => {
    const element = {
        ...current,
        index,
    };
    // See if the next one (if any) matches this one
    if (data[n + 1]?.thisweekNumber !== current.thisweekNumber) {
        ++index;
    }
    return element;
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The `map` version is probably more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the unique `thisweekNumber` values in an array. Sort that array, then get their indexes.

```js
const data = [
{name: 'A', thisweekNumber: 3}, 
{name: 'B', thisweekNumber: 5}, 
{name: 'C', thisweeknumber: 1}, 
{name: 'D', thisweekNumber: 4},
{name: 'E', thisweekNumber: 4}
];

const weeknumbers = [...new Set(data.map(e => e.thisweekNumber))].sort((a, b) => b - a);

data.forEach(el => el.index = weeknumbers.indexOf(el.thisweekNumber) + 1);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

not the prettiest solution but here you go:

```js
data.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.index =
    data[index - 1]?.index &&
    item.thisweekNumber === data[index - 1].thisweekNumber
      ? index
      : index + 1;
  if (item.index - data[index - 1]?.index > 1) {
    item.index -= 1;
  }
});
```

I use a simple forEach to iterate over all the elements in the array and use a ternary to set the value of index.
Then I check if the current item.index - previous item.index is > 1 and if it is i subtract 1 from the index (to keep the number sequence in order and not skip numbers)